# How to create listener to the server on thread that was created on service?

Tags: android, multithreading, listener, android-service

I have android service that creates new Thread.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    t = new ConnectionThread();
    t.start();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

On that Thread I'm opening socket connection and keeping it alive. It looks like this

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On this Thread I also have method that can send JSON message to the server. I call it from the service and service command is called from the fragment (on buttonclick) and it works fine.

```
public String sendJSON() {
    JSONObject messageJson = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject mJson = new JSONObject();

    try {
        mJson.put("Type", "ReadyToBind");
        messageJson.put("DeviceID", "myDeviceID");
        messageJson.put("AllowFastBind", true);
        mJson.put("Message", messageJson);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        out.println(mJson);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return message2;
}
```

But main problem is that server giving response in 3 seconds. This means it can give response instantly or it could wait 0-3 seconds and give different response.

How should I Implement listener to the server? It should listen to the commands recieved from server and react with the application (change current fragment UI).

I tried to create second thread on sendJson() method

```
        mThread = new ConnectionThread2ndLevel(socket);
        mThread.start();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long end = start + 3 * 1000; // 3 seconds * 1000 ms/sec
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end){
            message2 = mThread.getMessage();
        }
```

And on that Thread run() method i just read and on getMessage() I just return recieved message.

```
        scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        message2Thread = scanner.nextLine();
```

But this freezes application and user nothing can do during that time. Also not always I've got response from the server (maybe I got response and on while loop read blank line and then return it back.

So please, can you give me an advice or example how to do it in right way? It would be great that server listener could recieve message and instantly initiate changes on fragment (UI).